# < and quotation change to HTML entities in tinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

In DB, it is the following.

```
<img src="../../../../assets/images/frontpage/big_tree.jpg" alt="" 
width="516" height="200" />
```

But when it is in tinyMCE, all the <, > and " change to html entities like this.
So it does not display in FF.

```
&lt;img src=&quot;../../../../assets/images/frontpage/big_tree.jpg&quot; 
alt=&quot;&quot; width=&quot;516&quot; height=&quot;200&quot; /&gt;
```

How can I avoid this problem?

I have the following tinyMCE init

```
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        /* // if I want to add to a specific area then use this
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector : "mceEditor", // add class="mceEditor" where you want to add tinyMCE
        */

        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "advimage,advlink,media,contextmenu",
        //theme_advanced_buttons1_add_before : "newdocument,separator",
        theme_advanced_buttons1_add : "fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2_add : "separator,forecolor,backcolor,liststyle",
        theme_advanced_buttons2_add_before: "cut,copy,separator,",
        theme_advanced_buttons3_add_before : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "media",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        //extended_valid_elements : "hr[class|width|size|noshade]",
        extended_valid_elements : "span[class|align|style]",
        file_browser_callback : "ajaxfilemanager",
        paste_use_dialog : false,
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
        theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : true,
        apply_source_formatting : true,
        force_br_newlines : true,
        force_p_newlines : false,   
        relative_urls : true
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In php you can use [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Answer (score 2):

You need to eigther save the tinymce contents in the DB as is ("<" and ">" as real characters) or you will need to entity decode your database content before rendering them into the web page. Depending on your script language (perl, php, python,...) there are special functions to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue
I corrected it by adding

```
        $_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );
```